# Custom size class for child view controller

Tags: ios, adaptive-ui

I have an embedded `UIViewController` that is intended to take up the full width and some fraction of the height of its parent.

I expect it to take on vastly different heights for different scenarios within the same size class of its parent.

I would like to be able to design for these height changes using different size classes in interface builder.

Is there any way to tell this child view controller, for example, that it should have vertical size class `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact` even though its parent might have `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like lot of people facing this issue (differentiating iPad portrait and landscape orientations using size class). The below post seems to have a probable solution.

[Sizing class for iPad portrait and Landscape Modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633172/sizing-class-for-ipad-portrait-and-landscape-modes/28268200#28268200)