# Telling the difference between portrait and landscape iPad with Size Classes

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, autolayout, size-classes

How do you tell the difference between an iPad in portrait and landscape via Size Classes, if the are both in regular horizontal size and regular vertical size???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be Apple's intent to treat both iPad orientations as the same - but as a number of us are finding, there are very legitimate design reasons to want to vary the UI layout for iPad Portrait vs. iPad Landscape.

For answer to your question **[you can find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268200/3824808)**.