# iOS auto layout: how to design different layouts for iPad landscape and iPad portrait in Xcode storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, size-classes, ios-autolayout

I am new to size class and auto layout in iOS. I am practicing the same through a small application. Below is what I am trying to achieve through auto-layout and size-class. Below are the specific screenshots for iPad portrait and iPad landscape respectively.

[image: iPad portrait interface]
[image: iPad landscape interface]

**iPad Portrait**:: 3 subviews here i.e. gray view, green view, pink view.

gray view-  3/4th height of super view, 2/3th width of super view
green view- 3/4th height of super view, 1/3th width of super view
pink view- 1/4th height of super view, same width as super view

**iPad landscape**:: same 3 subviews as iPad portrait but at slightly different positions.

gray view-  same height as super view, 2/4th width of super view
green view- same height as super view, 1/4th width of super view
pink view- same height as super view, 1/4th width of super view

I am able to manage with auto layout as long as there are two subviews. But, I am unable to achieve what is described above. Also, I want to have different layout design in iPad portrait and landscape.

Comment: I am not sure why this is being down voted. The question here is very specific. How to differentiate between iPad portrait and landscape using size class? And I don't find any good answers on stack overflow.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I have same issue, and have only ever been met by same kind of answers you received from elitists who consider themselves too good to help anyone.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look also on new adaptive interface builder: "what's new in interface builder" from WWDC2014 https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/ and see designing different UIs for different screen sizes - big, small, default.

EDIT:
Let's start with creating single uiView inside the ViewController:
[uiview in uiviewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y5YG.png)

After that select your UIView and click the constraints editor in the lower-right corner (an "tie fighter" like icon).
[editing constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eduQ6.png)

Select the upper and left constraint to 0 (untick "constrain to margins"): [constrains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOvLT.png)

Control+drag from your view to the background view and select equal widths:[equal widths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReGyA.png)

Select your view and on the right side of the panel select the Size inspector. You have list of all constrains there. Select the Equal width to:Superview and click edit. Select the multiplier to e.g. 1/2: [proportional constrain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MayY.png).

Add the additional two views and play with constrains: adding the space to nearest neighbour and others to get what you want.

Important step: click on the w any h any on the bottom of the interface builder and select regular width|any height.[[w any h any](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa7FC.png)
First you created the general constrains. Now you will create More specific constrains for so called size-class (class representing the size of the screen depending on model and orientation of device). You can create different set of constrains like in my previous description.

I wish you luck.

Comment: Yeah, because iPad in landscape and portrait both have regular width and regular height. As far as I know you can distinguish them only in code using UITraitCollection, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28268200/991816)