# Change sizes after change orientation

Tags: ios, swift, size, orientation

```
func SetDeviceFontSizes()
{
    ...
    imgView.frame.size.width = 375        
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    SetDeviceFontSizes()
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    SetDeviceFontSizes()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SetDeviceFontSizes()
}            

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)        
    SetDeviceFontSizes()
}
```

I want to set sizes for labels and images (for old devices these sizes will be small).
But when I change orientation of device, the sizes return to default values in spite of function SetDeviceFontSizes().
How can I set frame sizes after change orientation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25667424/4475605

Comment: Stylistically, you could clean it up a bit. I'd put lifecycle methods in a section (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear) and your `setDeviceFontSizes` method below that. Also, methods should be in `camelCase`, not capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

```
var m_CurrentOrientation = UIDeviceOrientation()
```

**add this line in your viewdidload()**

```
 UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.deviceOrientationDidChange), name: .DidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

**perform your task in if condition**

```
func OrientationDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    var Orientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
    if Orientation == .LandscapeLeft || Orientation == .LandscapeRight {

    }
    else if Orientation == .Portrait {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure this will solve your problem, but you should call super in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewWillTransition`

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITraitCollection. Refer to this link
[How to translate this objective c traitCollection to swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278185/how-to-translate-this-objective-c-traitcollection-to-swift)

Do not call anything in viewWillLayoutSubviews() function.

Hope it helps you.