# Different layout for landscape and portrait iPad with storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, screen-orientation, size-classes

I've to develop an iPad app that should have a layout for portrait and a layout for landscape. This app should be able to work with iOS 8 and iOS 9. To design two different layout should I use 2 storyboards: one for the portrait layout and one for landscape layout or I can use only one storyboard with size classes?

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633172/sizing-class-for-ipad-portrait-and-landscape-modes/28268200#28268200) over stackoverflow, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to work with 2 different layout. Does anyone have an idea about how to work with a portrait layout and with a landscape layout with iPad? So you think it's better to use size classes or to use 2 different storyboard: one for landscape and one for portrait

Comment: Hi @lucgian841 - do you still seek the answer to this?  I can supply the answer if anyone's still reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your question you need to use size class for creating application. But in traitCollection you will only get **wRegular-hRegular for both landscape and portrait**.

result of log value of trait collection with statusBarOrientation.

[image]

All you can do is add make constraints active and inactive in

**-(void)updateViewConstraints {}** method based on **[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation**.

First you need to bind the constraints you have given to the view and make their objects in .h or .m file.

[image]

Then you need to change the **constant value of the constraint** or **make constraints active and inactive** based on your requirement.

[image]

**Result**:

1.) iPad Portrait View

[image]

2.) iPad Landscape View

[image]

This is one way by which you can layout in iPad. Hope it helps you solving your problem.