# Make some views independent to orientation change

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, landscape-portrait

How Can I make some of my UIViews to be orientation independent and some of them dependent. I'm looking for effect similar to this in standard iOS 9 Camera App when user change orientation from Portrait to Landscape. In Camera View Controller only left Icons and Right Icons are rotating but the internal view stays on position independently.

Comment: Kindly check my answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293073/different-layouts-in-portrait-and-landscape-mode/34297006#34297006

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati - Thanks for Your reply. I see Your answer is autolayout related and constraints switching along the transition. My question is rather how to block rotation in Center UIView (camera preview). Changing constraints don't let me block rotating for the UIView as far as I know.