# swift - How to have the UIView turn into full-screen when device rotate to landscape (iPhone/iPad)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fullscreen, landscape-portrait

When device rotate to `Landscape`, I would like to have red `UIView` be as full-screen while the blue `UIView` and `UIButton` is hidden from the screen.
While device rotate to `Portrait`, all of red `UIView`, blue `UIView` and `UIButton` will go back to the original position.
The above-mentioned devices include all type of `iPhone` and `iPad`.

Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

---

Following please find the diagram:-

[Portrait -image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqw8r.png)

[Landscape -image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIS2Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a quite similar to [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293073/different-layouts-in-portrait-and-landscape-mode) which has some useful answers. Hope this help you.