# Laying out equal sections on a view in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

[image]

Im wanting to setup my view within the storyboard so it lays out like the above image. The view has 2 seperate sections when landscape the share 50/50 horizontally then when portrait it rotates to 50/50 vertically.

What is the most appropriate way to set this up inside xcode interface builder? Can I use constraints to achieve this? This will need to be designed so it will scale to ipad and iphone as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, iPad's only have one type of layout for both landscape and portrait. I don't think there is a way to do what you want to do through the storyboard. Check out the following, maybe it'll help -> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633172/sizing-class-for-ipad-portrait-and-landscape-modes/28268200#28268200](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633172/sizing-class-for-ipad-portrait-and-landscape-modes/28268200#28268200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build a project to test. It works, check the screenshot

iPad in Portrait
[image: iPad in Portrait]
iPad in Landscape
[image: iPad in Landscape]

It can't be done in Storyboard, because iPad only got one layout in Storyboard.
but it's very simple to achieve what you need programmatically .

```
//ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *firstView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *secondView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.firstView];
    self.secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.secondView];
    [self setupSubViewLayout];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [self setupSubViewLayout];
}

- (void)setupSubViewLayout {
    CGFloat viewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGRect firstRect;
    CGRect secondRect;
    if (viewWidth > viewHeight) {
        firstRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth/2.0, viewHeight);
        secondRect = CGRectMake(viewWidth/2.0, 0, viewWidth/2.0, viewHeight);
    }else {
        firstRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight/2.0);
        secondRect = CGRectMake(0, viewHeight/2.0, viewWidth, viewHeight/2.0);
    }
    self.firstView.frame = firstRect;
    self.secondView.frame = secondRect;
}
```