# UIImageView use different image based on orientation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, interface-builder

On my project, the first screen has a full-screen image in the background. I would like to painlessly switch images depending on device and orientation. I have a storyboard scene with a full-view UIImage.

I already know how to use the Asset library to specify a different image for iPad / iPhone and 1x 2x 3x. It will automatically select the best image.

Is there a way to do the same thing for an orientation change? I have a different image that I would like to display when the iPad is in landscape.

Comment: You can specify image based on size class, but unfortunately landscape iPad is not a different size class!

Comment: I'm not sure you can use the image assets specifically for different orientations, but you can listen to an orientation change, and when orientation changes, you can pick the correct image asset. like change from asset "picture" to "picture-landscape" or something.

Comment: Bummer you can't do it with Size classes! It's so close.

Comment: This hack worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633172/sizing-class-for-ipad-portrait-and-landscape-modes/28268200#28268200

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you can do it directly from Image Assets. One way would be to do something like that:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue && UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        // Load First Image
    } else {
        // Load second Image
    }
}
```