# Set constraints for a view which should be presented as a vertical stack in portrait mode and as a horizontal stack in landscape mode

Tags: ios, autolayout

Can I use autolayout to provide different constraints for landscape and portrait orientations for an iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are describing is Size Classes (the Any / Any you see at the bottom of Interface Builder), see [Apple Docs, Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html). It can appear quite complex but is simpler than it looks and very useful, so stick with it.

Edit: additional info from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268200/2466193) regarding iPad landscape vs portrait orientations.

Comment: I suppose size classes are not helpful to distinguish the landscape and potrait mode for an iPad

Comment: @AbhilashaThapliyal Good point, but see my edit for another link that may help.