# how to load two different storyboard for IPad Landscape & IPad Portrait using Autolayout and size classes in ios 9 using obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i need to load different storyboard using Autolayout & width regular and height regular size classes for IPad portrait and IPad landscape.
i am using Autolayout now but i am not able to handle my ui design for both the landscape and portrait. your any suggestion would be highly appreciated. please any one help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you want to check this link... http://stackoverflow.com/a/28268200/6369570 and https://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 it's helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sizing class for iPad portrait and Landscape Modes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633172/sizing-class-for-ipad-portrait-and-landscape-modes)

Comment: Thanks for an update. i am using Width Regular & Height Regular Size Classes in iOS 9 using Autolayout and i need to load different storyboard for IPad Landscape & IPad Portrait only for three ViewController  and my other screen are working fine in both the orientation. so i would your any suggestion what should i do for these three ViewController. Thanks

Comment: Hi  Iwo Kucharski, i could'nt understand how to implement duplicate of Sizing class for iPad portrait and Landscape Modes. i am new in ios development please explain in detail. your any suggestion would be highly appreciated .Thanks in advance